# GWT under Liferay passing parameters

Tags: javascript, gwt, liferay

I am trying to show a GWT page into a Liferay portlet.
I' ve managed to load all pages (view.jsp calls the nocache.js from GWT) and page loads normally except that can' t read parameters giving to it throught browser.

I tried normal method of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?pid=100 and the method of Liferay to pass parameters to portlet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?p_p_id=_portletname&_portletname_pid=100

but nothing works...

Could someone give me directions on this?

Comment: how are you reading the parameters in GWT application?

Comment: I am using: Window.Location.getParameter("id")

Comment: Can you try to print the entire url and/or the map of parameters using Window.Location?